# Is ext-all-debug.js equivalent to ext-all.js plus debug statements?

Tags: extjs

I have read that ext-all.js is supposed to be used for production and ext-all-debug.js. is supposed to be used for debugging. Is it safe to assume that ext-all-debug.js is ext-all.js plus a lot of console.log statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ext-all.js` is the minified version of the `ext-all-debug.js`.

The `ext-all.js` version gain is that it greatly reduces the files size so that clients have to download less on the non-debug version. The `ext-all-debug.js` is provided so that you can debug through the extjs code. So they don't have any diference, such as added console.log's

Comment: what is preventing the develoepr from debugging through ext-all.js? he can set breakpoints insdie ext-all.js and use firebug to pause at each breakpoint? No?

Comment: When using `ext-all.js` to debug, Firebug don't display the correct number lines, since there are many "action's" in one line in the minified code. The same is to set breakpoints. Another disadvantage are the names of variables that are illegible in the minified version.